# Missing Class EventResize

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I'm using AS3 Flex 4.6.0 / Air 3.1 and i cannot find the `ResizeEvent`.

I added the following code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);
```

and want to have the function

```
private function onStageResize(ev:Event) : void //Here i want to use ev:ResizeEvent instead of ev:Event
{

}
```

I need the `ev.OldWidth` and `ev.OldHeight` property and i don't know why i cannot use

```
 import flash.event.ResizeEvent;
```

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: `import mx.events.ResizeEvent`  though I don't think the stage dispatches it - only flex components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import for `Event.RESIZE` is:

```
import flash.events.Event
```

Remember, that event will only be fired if the `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE` is set.

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        var swfWidthPrev:int;
        var swfHeightPrev:int;

        function resizeDisplay(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("~~~ resize event ~~~");
            trace("swfWidthPrev: " + swfWidthPrev);
            trace("swfHeightPrev: " + swfHeightPrev);
            trace("swfWidthCur: " + stage.stageWidth);
            trace("swfHeightCur: " + stage.stageHeight);
            swfWidthPrev = stage.stageWidth;
            swfHeightPrev = stage.stageHeight;
        }

        public function Main() {
            if(stage){
                stageReady();
            }else{
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageReady);
            }
        }

        private function stageReady(e:Event = null):void {
            swfWidthPrev = stage.stageHeight;
            swfHeightPrev = stage.stageWidth;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeDisplay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and code! I will do it like shown above,